# Alternative to Captcha - Your opinions for Ajax Tookit, JQuery Side lock, Drag and Drop

Tags: jquery, asp.net, captcha

Net Web Forms, I'm looking for a solution to avoid bot and spammer using my online contact form.

Captcha is pretty safe solution but sometimes could be to "Difficult" for inexperience user to use (in my opinion).

Here some solution alternative I found, I would like to know if you implement one of theme in a real world scenario, wich is the safest and easier to implement.

1 - Ajax Tookit [Nobot](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/NoBot/NoBot.aspx)

2 -Jquery [Side Locker](http://slidelock.parametercontraption.com/demo.php) (her one example
    but there are many of theme). What is the best?

3 - Drag and Drop solution [like this one](http://www.wozia.pt/blog/wcaptcha-a-better-captcha-alternative-jquery-captcha-plugin/)

### Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if a [honeypot captcha](http://www.google.com/search?q=honeypot+captcha) helps. It is simple, does not require JavaScript and does not require user interaction. It works because a typical spambot will try to fill out all fields present of a form. This you can detect on the server side:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="Name">
    <br />
    <label>Please leave this field empty</label>
    <input type="text" name="Email">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Server side code (PHP):

```
<?php
if($_POST["Email"] != "") {
    die("Thank you for spamming!");
}
```

Server side code (ASP.NET/C#):

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Request.Form["Email"] != "") {
        Response.Write("Thank you for spamming!");
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: I looked at this as well, really good for preventing bots, no good at protecting a system from automated attack.

Comment: @TheCodeKing: is a bot attack different from an automated attack?

Comment: Yes, one is manually crafted against a site (competition entry), the other just blindly follows a set of generic rules regardless.

Comment: @Gib: I've edited my post -- I am not a C# expert by the way.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but found a [ASP.NET MVC honeypot](https://nuget.org/packages/SimpleHoneypot.MVC) NuGet Package:

https://nuget.org/packages/SimpleHoneypot.MVC

Project Site:

https://github.com/webadvanced/Honeypot-MVC

Answer (score 0):

I would implement Jquery Side Locker and not bother with the other two (the third one didn't work on my browser).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this web app](http://goalcandy.com). I added a "mechanical action" anti-spam feature on the sign-up form. It's a drag & drop.

Comment: what do you mean by mechanical action?

Comment: @GibboK:  You have to drag the ball onto the square. It's not a text recognition type of solution, it's "mechanical". Pretty much like the 3rd example you gave.

Comment: thanks andrei but i cannot seet any ball on your link. what i'm missing?

Comment: @GibboK:  Sorry, I didn't realize I hadn't given you the complete URL. Try this one:  http://goalcandy.com/signup

Comment: Interesting, Do you know any tutorials explaining how to do it?

Comment: @GibboK:  Actually, I'm preparing to launch a blog on picselbocs.com, where I'll give this away for free, as a plug-in (among other things, such as a web chat module). Unfortunately, the blog is still a few days away from being ready :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar problem and decided to approach it first by blocking IP addresses from particularly "spammy" countries.  If you have an app that doesn't have a worldwide audience, this may be an option.

See https://serverfault.com/questions/305681/iis-7-address-restrictions-importing-list-to-block-china-and-korea-ips for a possible approach in an IIS7 environment.

Comment: Blocking and entire country seems a bit harsh :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your intent. Anti bot protection doesn't really require a captcha. There a few solutions that take advantage of the way these work to block them, the fact they don't have javasript enabled for instance. The HoneyPot also works well, taking advantage of the form greedy nature of bots.

If on the other hand you also wish to stop attackers from writing automated scripts then it does require more effort. I haven't looked at the ones you mentioned in detail but they look on the face of it like they would do the job. The thing to be weary of is reliability, localization, and performance. This is where the smaller less well known solutions usually fall down compared with say reCaptcha.

Yes it is a sweeping generalisation, not saying it's always the case just be sure to take in into consideration. I've looked at a few that all suffer on one of these points.